# how to construct the Z-function corresponding to Davenport-Helbron L-function?

Tags: riemann-zeta, l-functions

See https://aimath.org/news/gl3/zfunction.html

Actually, this question doesnt make sense, the Davenport-Heilbronn "zeta function" isn't even an L-series so it isn't right to call it a "zeta function" it's only a function which shares one particular symmetry of a subset of its zeros ... since its not an L-series there is no Z-function corresponding to it

An L-function is a Dirichlet series
L(s) = ∑n an  n-s
with certain special properties. For the purpose of this discussion, the relevant property is the functional equation
Λ(s)    =   Qs ∏j Γ(λj s +μj)   L(s)
    =   ε $\Lambda (1-s)$ .

where

- L(s)  The L-function
- s=$\sigma$ +i t a complex number
- an    The Dirichlet series coefficients of the L-function, normalized so that a1=1. The (very deep!) Ramanujan conjecture asserts that an = O(n&epsilon). This implies (but is stronger than) the Dirichlet series converges for σ>1.
- Γ     The Gamma function
- λj    Positive real numbers. It is conjectured that one can take λj = ½ for all j . The number 2 ∑ &lambdaj is called the degree of the L-function, which is conjectured to be an integer.
- μj    Numbers with non-negative real parts.
- Q     A positive number.
  ε   A number with absolute value 1, called the sign of the functional equation.
- Complex conjugate, operating on functions by f*(z) := f(z*)*, where the * on the right side is conjugation in the usual sense.

where it states that the Z  function can be constructed for an arbitrary L functions such that its real-valued on the real-line and shares the same zeros as the L function (after transforming)

The functional equation can also be written in an asymmetric form
L(s) = ε X(s) L*(1-s), where X(s) can be obtained by rearranging the functional equation written above.

Finally, we have the Z-function associated to L, defined by
$Z(t) = (ε X(½ + i t))^½ L(½+i t)$ .

In https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.06328.pdf they demonstrate that the Davenport-Heilbron "zeta function" is not even an L function, but a linear combination of two. so they only satisfy a "Riemann zeta"-like functional equation, so the conclusions drawn from it aren't even applicable to all L functions.

"We are reluctant to call these zeros counterexamples to the Riemann Hypothesis ( RH ) since the function f  s  is not a Dirichlet L - function for which the generalized RH has been stated , neither does it belong to the Selberg class for which the Grand RH is expected to be true . They are simply an illustration of the fact that a Riemann - type of functional equation implies this symmetry of some non trivial zeros with respect to the critical line . Functions of this type can be constructed for an arbitrary modulus q possessing complex conjugate characters "

Comment: I know that the DH zeta function has a Dirichlet character which repeats the sequence $[1,\xi,-\xi,-1,0]$ where $\xi={\frac {\sqrt {10-2\,\sqrt {5}}}{\sqrt {5}-1}}= 1.902113033$ so why should I  "start there" none of the terms there are non-Real. It seems like arblib has done a good job of implementing the evaluation of just what I am looking for, Dirichlet series with cyclic values http://arblib.org/acb_dirichlet.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character#Modulus_5

Comment: @user1952009 so it is of the type $\chi_0 (n)$ ? this one? http://www.lmfdb.org/Character/Dirichlet/5/1 from this group http://www.lmfdb.org/Character/Dirichlet/5/

Comment: @user1952009 http://www.lmfdb.org/L/Character/Dirichlet/5/2  I see

Answer (score 0):

Let $$F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n ^{-s}, \qquad \Lambda(s) = \varepsilon Q^{s} \prod_{m=1}^M \Gamma(\omega_m  s+\mu_m) F(s), \qquad \Lambda(s) = \overline{\Lambda(1-\overline{s})}$$ an [L-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_class) or a Dirichlet series with a functional equation.

Then  $\Lambda(1/2+it) = \overline{\Lambda(1-(1/2-it))}$ so that $Z(t) = \xi(1/2+it)$ is real for $t$ real

The basic examples are

- $\zeta(s)$ :  $\ Z(t)$ is even,
- $L(s,\chi_5)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_5 n^{-s}$ where [$\chi_5 = [1,i,-i,-1,0]$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character#Modulus_5) : $\  Z(t)$ has [no trivial symmetry](http://www.lmfdb.org/L/Character/Dirichlet/5/2/)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170824/why-does-the-myth-persist-that-the-davenport-heilbron-zeta-function-is-a-funct

Comment: Actually, this question doesnt make sense, the Davenport-Heilbronn "zeta function" isn't even an L-series so it isn't right to call it a "zeta function" it's only a function which shares one particular symmetry of a subset of its zeros ... since its not an L-series there is no Z-function corresponding to it

Comment: That's why I mentioned Dirichlet series with a functional equation (i.e. it can have no Euler product) @crow

Comment: well fuggit, the RH must be true, no one can even construct an example of one with the zeros off the line

Comment: @reuns Is there a known reference to compute the number of zeros $N(T)$ up to a height $T$ above the real axis inside the critical strip for the D-H Zeta function? Thank you