# Is there a zeta function(with a Dirichlet series) having known roots off the critical line?

Tags: roots, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

Is there a zeta function(with a Dirichlet series) having known roots off the critical line?

I thought there was something like the Hilldebrand-Davis zeta function or something like that, but I can't remember exactly what it was.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably thinking of the Davenport-Heilbronn zeta function. The original paper is:

[On the Zeros of Certain Dirichlet Series - Davenport, Heilbronn](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1112/jlms/s1-11.4.307).

You'll likely find it useful to read section 10.25 (page 282) of [Titmarsh's book](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Titchmarsh%20E.C.%20The%20theory%20of%20the%20Riemann%20zeta-function%20(2ed.,%20Oxford,%201986)(T)(418s)_MCsf_.pdf) for a slightly easier example of proving that a certain zeta function has a zero to the right of the critical strip. A more involved proof (see first link) can show that the Davenport Heilbronn zeta function has a root inside the critical strip, but off the critical strip. There's also nice numerical computations here:

[Zeros of the Davenport-Heilbronn Counterexample - Balanzario, et. al.](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2007-76-260/S0025-5718-07-01999-0/S0025-5718-07-01999-0.pdf)

Comment: It isnt actually a dirichlet series. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170370/how-to-construct-the-z-function-corresponding-to-davenport-helbron-l-function